# JPA - Many to Many - Foreign key violated when create / update

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, insert-update

First of all, I'm sorry if my english is not the best but i will do my best to explain my problem.

I am actually trying to save an object in my database, but i have a PSQLException saying that i cant save without saving my first object (problem of foreign key).

So, i have a object, Mission, that contains Frais. Here is my class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_MISSION")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Mission implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8050548742704457221L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_mission_t_frais", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fraiss_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Frais> fraiss = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Here is my class "Frais" :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FRAIS")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Frais implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4881527916470482329L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "fraiss")
    private Set<Mission> missions = new HashSet<>(0);

}
```

As you can see, when i try to save a new Mission, i want my data saved in a database table named 't_mission_t_frais' which contains fraiss_id and missions_id.

But for now, i cant save it cause of this error : '
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: an insert or update statement on the table "t_mission_t_frais" violates the key constraint
foreign "fk_frais_mission_id"
  Detail: The key (missions_id) = (60261) is not present in the table "t_mission".'

Here is my MissionService :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MissionService {
    @Autowired
    private MissionRepository missionRepository;

    public void save(Mission mission) {
       missionRepository.save(mission);
    }
 }
```

As i am new in Java, i think i missconfigured something in my Mission class, but i guess my mission is not saved first (before the frais one) which blocks the transaction of saving...

I already tried to replace 'save' by 'saveAndFlush', and do other stuff without the result i would like...

Can you guys could help me if you have some ideas?

EDIT :

my mission is created with a front application (Angular) and sent in JSON format. Here is an exemple :

```
id: 67114,
fraiss: [
    {
        actif: true
        fraisType: {id: 44881, libelle: "Indemnité", actif: true}
        actif: true
        id: 44881
        libelle: "Indemnité"
        id: 60261
        libelle: "53,50€ par nuité"
        missions: []
    },
    {
        actif: true
        fraisType: {id: 136, libelle: "Frais", actif: true}
        actif: true
        id: 136
        libelle: "Frais"
        id: 23986
        libelle: "54€ par jour"
        missions: []
    }
]

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/manage/missions", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public void create(@RequestBody Mission mission) {
         log.debug("REST request to save Mission : {}", mission);
         missionService.save(mission);
     }
```

Comment: Can you provide the SQL statements that are executed and the code where you create Mission and Frais?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli My mission is created with a post request, here is an exemple of the JSON format : 
id: 67114,
fraiss: [
 {
  actif: true
  fraisType: {id: 44881, libelle: "Indemnité", actif: true}
  actif: true
  id: 44881
  libelle: "Indemnité"
  id: 60261
  libelle: "53,50€ par nuitée à partir du 25ème mois"
  missions: []
 },
 {
  actif: true
  fraisType: {id: 136, libelle: "Frais", actif: true}
  actif: true
  id: 136
  libelle: "Frais de route"
  id: 23986
  libelle: "54€ par jour"
  missions: []
 }
]

How can i see the SQL statements with IntelliJ ?

Comment: You can't just save what you get from JSON. You have to make sure that all relationships are set like you defined it.

Comment: I didnt put all my classes because they are very long, but i can save them if i have the "fraiss :[] " (it is when i have object not empty that i can't save) in my JSON.
I know my JSON is good, i'm pretty sure the problem comes from the JPA's configuration but i dont know where

Comment: okay i got news, looks like i'm trying to save my object t_mission_t_frais in the wrong way -> im saving (fraiss_id, missions_id) instead of (missions_id, fraiss_id). 

Switch the @JoinTable(name = "t_mission_t_frais",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fraiss_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }) by missions_id in the first and fraiss_id in the second way gives me a stakoverflow, and put it in the Frais class doesnt work too. 

I'll give u more details if i see others things

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about my JPA's configuration. The saving of the mission was in the wrong way : that was triying to save in my t_mission_t_frais (fraiss_id, missions_id) a new value of (missions_id, fraiss_id), occuring a PSQLException because the mission didnt exist

In my Mission class, my "JOIN TABLE" was declared in the wrong way  :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "t_mission_t_frais",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fraiss_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Frais> fraiss = new HashSet<>();
```

But only do this modification was doing me stackoverflow, so i had to modify my Frais class too :

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "t_mission_t_frais",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "missions_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fraiss_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Set<Mission> missions = new HashSet<>(0);
```

And i can now save my objects ! Thanks Simon for the help !